# Skip expensive methods from PHP unit testing

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I would like to skip expensive method in production Lavavel project. This is how I skip

```
class HomePageTest extends TestCase
{
   use WithFaker, RefreshDatabase;
    /** @test */
    public function something_testing()
    {
      if (  env('APP_ENV') == 'local' ) {
        $response = $this->get('/expensive-service');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
      } else {
         $this->assertTrue(true);
      }
    }
}
```

The above codes work. But, I feel that there would be elegant way to skip testing method for some states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP unit you can mark tests with [groups](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html#group) e.g.

```
class HomePageTest extends TestCase
{
   use WithFaker, RefreshDatabase;
    /** 
     * @test 
     * 
     * @group notProduction
     */
    public function something_testing()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/expensive-service');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Laravel comes with a `phpunit.xml.dist` and you can update that file as below:

```
<groups>
  <exclude>
    <group>notProduction</group>
  </exclude>
</groups>
```

Docs on the configuration options are [here](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#the-groups-element)

For local testing you can create a local `phpunit.xml` without the exclusion option.

Laravel tests will use `phpunit.xml` if it exists otherwise they fall back to using `phpunit.xml.dist` so this way you can control what test configuration runs in each environment